# cups "invalid deviceid" when trying to use USB printer

Tags: linux, printing, printer, arch-linux, manjaro

Using Manjaro 22, cups is outputting the follow log messages when I try to print to an HP Deskjet 2510 (driver: `Current - HP Deksjet 2510 Series, hpcups 3.22.10`):

```
Jan 04 12:52:45 compy-manjaro hp[24585]: io/hpmud/musb.c 427: Found interface conf=0, iface=1, altset=0, index=1
Jan 04 12:52:45 compy-manjaro hp[24585]: io/hpmud/musb.c 389: Active kernel driver on interface=1 ret=0
Jan 04 12:52:45 compy-manjaro hp[24585]: io/hpmud/musb.c 515: invalid claim_interface 7/1/2: Device or resource busy
Jan 04 12:52:45 compy-manjaro hp[24585]: io/hpmud/musb.c 427: Found interface conf=0, iface=2, altset=0, index=9
Jan 04 12:52:45 compy-manjaro hp[24585]: io/hpmud/musb.c 389: Active kernel driver on interface=2 ret=0
Jan 04 12:52:45 compy-manjaro hp[24585]: io/hpmud/musb.c 535: claimed ff/4/1 interface
Jan 04 12:52:45 compy-manjaro hp[24585]: io/hpmud/musb.c 769: invalid deviceid ret=-9: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jan 04 12:52:45 compy-manjaro hp[24585]: io/hpmud/musb.c 561: released ff/4/1 interface
Jan 04 12:52:45 compy-manjaro hp[24585]: prnt/backend/hp.c 824: ERROR: open device failed stat=12: hp:/usb/Deskjet_2510_series?serial=CN37V3JPNS05QX
```

I'm using KDE and the Print Queue shoulds the priter as "paused" with an option to "Resume Printer". Clicking this makes it try to print the document in the queue again and the same info is output to the log.

[image: Print Queye]

This also disables the printer, as shown in the Printer Properties (`system-config-printer`) (see Enabled checkbox):

[image: Printer Properties]

I'm not sure what to do to get the printer to work. I've tried removing/re-adding it multiple times, and have tried different USB ports (using ports directly on the motherboard).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this one was a new level of dumb -- mixed with poor error reporting in the software (cups?).

*I had the output door on the printer closed*, which caused the printer to throw an error. However, this error wasn't displayed to me in any way whatsoever when printing from Linux.

I ended up printing what I needed using my wife's Windows laptop and it proudly showed me the "output door closed" message when I tried to print.